# SAS Data each person should appear only once

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following table where I have some combinations for some subjects.

SubjectSet1, SubjectSet2,More info...

1,1

1,2

1,3

2,2

2,3

2,4

3,1

3,3

3,2

4,1

I need a way to program SAS so that each subject will appear exactly once. Giving for example the following results:

SubjectSet1, SubjectSet2,More info...

1,2

2,4

3,3

4,1

Comment: What are your rules for choosing subject1/2 pair?  How do you choose "1,2" not "1,1" or "1,3" for example?

Answer (score 1):

Question is ambiguous. But if you want to go from:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,2
2,3
2,4
3,1
3,3
3,2
4,1
```

to something like:

```
1,2
2,4
3,3
4,1
```

And assuming your table **Table1** has two fields named **Field1** and **Field2**, you need a PROC SQL but with only a distinct on the first field.
Something like

```
select distinct Field1
from Table1
```

Or you can do the same with a NODUPKEY in PROC SORT:

```
proc sort data=Table1 NODUPKEY;
by Field1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to select samples at random such that each subject appears at most once in each position, one solution is below:

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input SubjectSet1  SubjectSet2;
rannum=ranuni(10);
datalines;
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,2
2,3
2,4
3,1
3,3
3,2
4,1
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by rannum;
run;

data want;
set have;
length subj1list subj2list $32767;
retain subj1list subj2list '|';
*if the current record is not in either of the subject lists, then...;
if not find(subj1list,cats('|',SubjectSet1,'|'))
and not find(subj2list,cats('|',SubjectSet2,'|'))
then do;
    *add it to each of the lists and output into the want dataset;
    subj1list=cats(subj1list,SubjectSet1,'|');
    subj2list=cats(subj2list,SubjectSet1,'|');
    output;
end;
drop subj1list subj2list;
run;
```

I add a random number, sort by it, and then use a pair of character variables as simplistic hash tables to store the previously selected respondents.  This solution is reasonably fast but has limitations, particularly in the maximum character size in SAS (32767), so it couldn't be used for more than a few thousand records.

The superior solution would be using an actual hash table, but I'm not sure that isn't excessively complicated.  If this solution won't work due to sample size issues that could be written reasonably easily.

Comment: Note that you are not necessarily going to get the rows you asked for in the original post, nor will you always get 4 - change the seed in ranuni from 10 to 7 for example and you will get 3, because some row with a 1 in subjectset2 is chosen prior to 4,1 becoming available.

Answer (score 1):

If you **REALLY** do not care which row you want to keep, you can use the NODUPKEY option of PROC SORT:

```
data have;
   input subject somevar;
   datalines;
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 1
3 3
3 2
4 1
run;

proc sort nodupkey data=have out=want;
   by subject;
run;
```

This results in an output data set with unique observations for `subject`.  The row retained will be the first that occurs in the source data for a distinct value of the `BY` variables.  Use with caution and make sure this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `proc sql`:

```
select distinct subjectSet1, SubjectSet2
from t;
```

Comment: I don't think that would work, given it would return all of the original dataset...